# How to debug website that is not loading on any IOS devices?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, nginx, next.js

I have a website developed using react + next.js which works fine in every platform except for ios devices. When the website is accessed using any browser from an ios device, the browser loading bar goes halfway and then remains stuck showing a blank page.

I'm not being able to debug since no errors are showing up. The website works on mac too but the problem is just with ios devices.

The website is hosted on AWS lightsail with NGINX server and SSL certificate installed from LetsEncrypt.

I really need some help in debugging this issue.

***Update

So, I have managed to access the developer console using the browserstack iOS simlation and these errors were being logged continuously. [Screenshot of developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zd8h.png)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using Safari and mocking the User Agent in the Develop menu?

Comment: @juliomalves , the website does load after changing the user agent to Safari - iPhone iOS from my chrome browser. 

I'm not sure whether the issue is due to wrong server configuration or bug in client/server-side code.

Comment: Can you try reproducing it on Safari browser specifically (mocking the User Agent in the Develop menu)? That's what iOS devices would use.

Comment: @juliomalves , Just done it from a mac using safari, the website is working fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved. The problem was due to incorrect configuration of an npm module - body-scroll-lock. For some reason, the problem was occuring only in iOS devices without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you tell exactly how you fixed this issue?. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @TirlochanArora , I had an npm package named body-scroll-lock which was causing this issue. Uninstalling it fixed the issue. Apparently that npm package is not compatible with ios devices. You can try checking if you have any npm modules that have compatibility issues. 

One way of doing that would be by uninstalling any modules that you had installed recently until the point when everything was working fine. 

Are you able to see any errors in the console?